# Angular 4 with material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to implement "Angular-Material" with Angular4. I made all setup from official site of angular material [angular.material.io][1]

[1]: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started but when trying to run project by npm start, getting following error:

> node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button/button.d.ts(40,22):
>   error TS2420: Class 'MdButton' incorrectly implements interface
>   'CanDisable'.   Property 'disabled' is private in type 'MdButton' but
>   not in type 'CanDisable'.
>   node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button/button.d.ts(40,39):
>   error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof
>   MdButtonBase' is not a constructor function type.
>   node_modules/@angular/material/typings/checkbox/checkbox.d.ts(43,22):
>   error TS2420: Class 'MdCheckbox' incorrectly implements interface
>   'CanDisable'.   Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdCheckbox'.
>   node_modules/@angular/material/typings/checkbox/checkbox.d.ts(43,41):
>   error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof
>   MdCheckboxBase' is not a constructor function type.
>   node_modules/@angular/material/typings/radio/radio.d.ts(24,22): error
>   TS2420: Class 'MdRadioGroup' incorrectly implements interface
>   'CanDisable'.   Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdRadioGroup'.
>   node_modules/@angular/material/typings/radio/radio.d.ts(24,43): error
>   TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof
>   MdRadioGroupBase' is not a constructor function type.
>   node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.d.ts(14,22):
>   error TS2420: Class 'MdSlideToggle' incorrectly implements interface
>   'CanDisable'.   Property 'disabled' is missing in type
>   'MdSlideToggle'.
>   node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.d.ts(14,44):
>   error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof
>   MdSlideToggleBase' is not a constructor function type.
>   node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slider/slider.d.ts(26,22):
>   error TS2420: Class 'MdSlider' incorrectly implements interface
>   'CanDisable'.   Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdSlider'.
>   node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slider/slider.d.ts(26,39):
>   error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof
>   MdSliderBase' is not a constructor function type.

Somebody, please help me to fix above.

Comment: Please rearrange the content in the question properly.

Comment: A package is broken, its persistent state at any time. Is not possible to use them soon time.

Answer (score 3):

Double check your package.json dependencies and devDependencies file and find your typescript install. Make certain it is 2.2.0 or greater.

```
"typescript": "~2.2.0"
```

If you make a change, be sure to then run

```
$ npm update -D
```

If you have it installed globally **and there is no typescript line in your package.json file**, run

```
$ npm install -g typescript@2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer, i have added the screenshot of package.json file :

Go to your package.json and check dependencies and devDependies as shown below:
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daCvP.png)

**Step 1:** If the **typescript version** is **less than 2.2.0** , change it to the latest vesrion as shown in the image.

**Step2:** Run **npm update -D** in your terminal

**Step3:** To globally update the typescript , execute following command:

**npm install -g typescript@version-number**